# How can I get 'diff' to show only added and deleted lines? If diff can't do it, what tool can? Take-2

Tags: diff

I have 2 sorted files produced by

```
xxx>find /store -type f -print | sort > /tmp/invent.txt
xxx>find /fbkup -type f -print | sort > /tmp/backup.txt
```

I want from diff a file name list of files missing in /store which are still on /backup, without any < > annotations, just one output file containing exactly the same records from /tmp/backup for which there was no match on /tmp/invent.txt.

```
xxx>diff -??? /tmp/invent.txt /tmp/invent.txt | xargs ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in `cat /tmp/invent.txt`; do grep ^$i$ /tmp/backup.txt >/dev/null || echo $i ; done
```

This will `echo` all names in `/tmp/invent.txt` which is not in `/tmp/backup.txt`

**Edit**

I found another way using `diff` :- (`diff -r dir1 dir2`)

> `-r,  --recursive` **means** `Recursively compare any subdirectories found.`

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/dir dir2/dir/dir

$ diff -r dir1 dir2
Only in dir2/dir: dir

$ touch dir1/file{a..d}

$ touch dir2/file{a..d}

$ touch dir2/dir/file{a..d}

$ echo hi >  dir2/filea

$ diff -q -r dir1 dir2
Only in dir2/dir: dir
Only in dir2/dir: filea
Only in dir2/dir: fileb
Only in dir2/dir: filec
Only in dir2/dir: filed
Files dir1/filea and dir2/filea differ
```

Comment: clumsy... clumsy... 100,000 x 100,000 = 10 billion compares 1

Comment: @Andreas see my edit. I found a more efficient way to compare directories. :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to find a solution. See above, read my problem description, look how the 2 text files were obtained, aren't you solving another, very different problem?

Comment: Hmmm... Using `diff -r` you can find out the difference between two directories. Thats it.

Answer (score 3):

Diff your files, then use awk to find the lines you want (`/^<`), strip the leading bit (`gsub(/^</,"")`), and print the matched line.

```
diff file1 file2 | awk '/^</ {gsub(/^</,""); print}'
```

So if you want a one liner you could even do something like this.

```
diff <(cd /store ; find . -type f -print | sort) \
     <(cd /fbkup ; find . -type f -print | sort) | \
     awk '/^</ {gsub(/^</,""); print}'
```

Comment: very good ! it probably wont get better than that until the author of comm adds a -n switch to negate the -1 and -2 option.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `diff`, use [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) instead. Since your input files are already `sort`ed, the following should produce exactly the output you requested:

```
join -v 2 /tmp/invent.txt /tmp/backup.txt > /tmp/in-backup-but-not-invent.txt
```

(If the file paths in either `/tmp/backup.txt` or `/tmp/invent.txt` contain whitespace, then `join` may not work correctly with the options given above. In that case, you will have to look at using the `-t` option, to specify a non-whitespace char as the field separator for `join`. You would want to choose as field separator a char that does not actually appear in any of your file paths. Something like `|` or `\` would probably suffice.)

Answer (score 2):

Diff can prolly do this, but im too lazy to check.

Try `comm`. `comm -2 -3` or `comm -1 -2` which'll give lines only in file A, or lines only in file B.

Comment: This seems to be what he wants, but according to my manpage it looks like `-1` and `-2` turn OFF those outputs, not on.  `comm -23` turns off "lines unique to file 2" and "lines in both files" to print only lines in file 1